# ListView não aparece

Tags: android

Apos horas de analise de codigo ainda nao consigo encontrar o erro simplesmente não aparece a minha lista com os horarios que são recebidos por json ! Tirei codigo que não achei necessario para o erro. 
**O código esta a conseguir receber o json penso que o problema esteja aqui :**

```
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(HorariosActivity.this, horariosList, R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] {TAG_TITLE, TAG_DATESTART},
                    new int[] {R.id.title, R.id.dateStart});
            listaHorarios.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**A minha Activity:**

```
public class HorariosActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "Titulo";
    private static final String TAG_DATESTART = "DataInicio";
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private Context context;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private Toolbar mToolbarBottom;

    String horarios2;
    ListView  listaHorarios;


boolean estado;
    String link ;
    String varjson ="horarioHora";
    ArrayList<String> horarios = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> linhas3 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> horariosList;
    private Drawer.Result navigationDrawerLeft;





    private OnCheckedChangeListener mOnCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(IDrawerItem iDrawerItem, CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.horarios);
        estado=true;




        btnpesquisa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnpesquisa);
        btnparagens = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnparagens);


        tvCoordinate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Localizacaotv);
        link="http://dagobah.grifin.pt/tiagocoelho/horariosAndroid.php?linhaid=4&paragemid=36";
        new Download().execute();

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_main);
        mToolbar.setTitle("Tumg");
        mToolbar.setSubtitle("Marinha Grande");
        listaHorarios = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listEventos);

        mToolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


        GPSManager gps = new GPSManager(
                HorariosActivity.this);
        gps.start();
  callConnection();


    }

    public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String out = null;

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                String url_all_empresas =  link;

                final HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();

                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);

                HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url_all_empresas);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                out = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return out;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            estado = true;
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(HorariosActivity.this, "A autenticar", "A contactar o servidor, por favor, aguarde alguns instantes.", true, false);
        }


        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsa = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    horarios2= jsa.getString(varjson);
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    String estado= jsa.getString("horarioEstado");

                    HashMap<String, String> evento = new HashMap<>();
                    evento.put("horarioHora", horarios2);
                    evento.put("horarioEstado", estado);
                    horariosList.add(evento);


                }



                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(HorariosActivity.this, horariosList, R.layout.list_item,
                        new String[] {TAG_TITLE, TAG_DATESTART},
                        new int[] {R.id.title, R.id.dateStart});
                listaHorarios.setAdapter(adapter);
                estado = false;




            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    }










    }





}
```

**O meu horarios.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tb_main"

        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#82d808" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listEventos"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**O meu list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="dateStart"
        android:id="@+id/dateStart"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="title"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Não dá nenhum erro ? O mapa tá sendo populado certinho ?

Comment: O que quer dizer com mapa ta sendo populando? Não está a dar erro

Comment: Pelo que entendi você transforma os dados recebidos no JSON em um HashMap e insere eles em uma lista certo ? Este mapa está recebendo os dados corretamente ? Talvez debugando ele você repare se a chave e o valor estão de acordo com o que você espera na hora de montar o adapter

Answer (score 1):

Fala Tiago,

O problema é na hora que você declara essas TAGS, elas não estão sendo identificadas pelo SimpleAdapter.

Fiz um teste aqui e funcionou, declare seu To e From da seguinte forma:

```
String[] from = new String[] {TAG_TITLE, TAG_DATESTART};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.dateStart};
```

Com isso, você define que todos os títulos ficarão no id R.id.title e as datas ficarão no id R.id.dateStart.

Na hora do looping, onde você monta o Map, faça dessa forma:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> horariosList = new ArrayList<>();
   for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
      map.put(TAG_TITLE, horarios2);
      map.put(TAG_DATESTART, estado);
      horariosList.add(map);
   }
```

Dessa forma, você coloca cada elemento no seu devido lugar.

E por fim, na hora de declarar o seu adapter, faça dessa forma:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, horariosList, R.layout.list_item, from, to);
listaHorarios.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Se não der certo, avisa ai que te ajudo.

Abraços.